# SFP compatibility on QLogic FC HBA and Cisco FC SFPs

Tags: cisco-nexus, transceiver, fibrechannel

I do have a server featuring a dual port QLogic FC HBA supporting 2/4/8G interface speed. On the other end there is a Cisco Nexus 5020 with N5K-M1008 module supporting 1/2/4G interface speeds. This is a lab setup.

The Cisco module was chosen because the 8G version is much more expensive. As FC SFPs I'd use DS-SFP-FC4G-SW on the Cisco side, but the QLogic currently has 8G HP SFPs.

There are two options now:

- Using HP 4G transceivers (HP AJ715A) in the QLogic HBA which would likely work
- Using DS-SFP-FC4G-SW on the QLogic side as well

I am considering that as I do have the Cisco ones but would need to buy the HP ones. Would the Cisco transceivers work (note I am not asking for being supported) on the QLogic HBA?

Comment: If it accepts the HP branded ones, it will likely accept the Cisco tagged one as well. If the HP one is multi-rate (and almost always are), it should work at whatever speed both sides can support. (i.e. 4)

Comment: I was not aware that the transceivers are also multi rate and can go down to 4 if needed. It it hard to find information or datasheet for this transceiver (AJ718A). I will give this a try first and then report back if that works. Thanks!

Comment: @RickyBeam I found more information here (http://www.sfpex.com/aj718a) actually indicating a speed of `1.0625Gbps~8.5Gbps` and an application `Application: Multi-rate FC`. Please post your comment as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it accepts the HP branded ones, it will likely accept the Cisco tagged one as well. If the HP one is multi-rate (and almost always are), it should work at whatever speed both sides can support. (i.e. 4)